# Как сделать границы для scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

У меня есть скрол, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать ему явные границы в виде линий по четырём краям?

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnAdd"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

[image: примерно так]

Comment: у него же есть атрибут background - назначьте свой бэкграйнд [с шейпом-прямоугольником](http://devdeeds.com/how-to-create-rectangle-shape-using-xml-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте картинку Draw 9-patch по [Такому примеру](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/draw9patch.php)
и добавьте ее как атрибут `background` к вашему `ScrollView`.
Некоторые уже готовые можно найти в папке: android_sdk\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-hdpi.
[Тут еще почитать об этом](https://habr.com/ru/post/113623/)
[И тут](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html?hl=ru#TaskUse9Patch)